# Owl carousel single item

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects, jquery-events, owl-carousel

When I use single item in owl carousel the loop doesn't stop. I want it to be stop for one item, and when I add other items it will start working. Following is my code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:false,
dots:false,
responsive:{
    320:{
        stagePadding:11,
        items:1
    },
    425:{
        stagePadding:45,
        items:1
    },
    768:{
        items:2
    },
    1000:{
        items:3
    }
})
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without seeing the rest of your code - however you should probably set `loop` programmatically, something like:

```js
const numChildren = $('#container .child').length; // just an example
const isLooping = numChildren > 1;
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: isLooping,
    ...
});
```